# Problems with the sticky bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to present myself as an amateur WordPress developer for the very first time. I'm just entering in this whole world with CSS which apparently is one of the easiest. But still, I'm having problems with the sticky bar...

There is no problem with the responsive version of the sticky bar. But when scrolling on the desktop preview, it gets sticky until the content starts.
I suppose it's due to the fact that the element is inside the header .div and the content is part of another .div.

Could you recommend to me how to fix it or what to check?
I am putting code on CCS additional option of Wordpress and that's what I have.

```
#header {
background: #fff;
z-index:1!important;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #293133;
position: sticky!important;
top: 0px!important;
}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: please share some HTML to help you determine what the best approach could be

Comment: The first approach is to set the z-index to a higher level. For example, `z-index: 999;` It could be that your Navabr is sticky, but hidden behind other content.

Comment: For what I can get, the problem is that inside the div body-core I have another div which is content. Could this be the problem?